# Find the largest number of increasing and decreasing elements of the matrix, going in a row

Tags: java, arrays

I wrote a method for finding and deriving the largest number of increasing (decreasing) elements of the matrix, going in a row. But it seems that the code is not quite good.

```
private void findLargestIncreasingAndDecreasingElements() {
    int[][] matrix = getMatrix();
    int[] oneArray = new int[matrix.length * matrix.length];
    int r = 0;
    int min = 0;
    int max = 0;
    int h = 0;
    int m = 0;
    int h1 = 0;
    for (int[] x : matrix) {
        int c = 0;
        for (int z : x) {
            oneArray[c++] = z;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < oneArray.length - 1; i++) {
        if (oneArray[i] < oneArray[i + 1]) {
            r += 1;
            if (r > max) {
                max = r;
                h = i + 1;
            }
        } else {
            r = 0;
        }
        if (oneArray[i] > oneArray[i + 1]) {
            m += 1;
            if (m > min) {
                min = m;
                h1 = i + 1;
            }
        } else {
            m = 0;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Maximum sequence of increasing numbers:");
    int[] l = new int[max + 1];
    System.arraycopy(oneArray, (h - max), l, 0, (max + 1));
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(l) + " " + (max + 1));
    System.out.println("Maximum sequence of decreasing numbers:");
    int[] t = new int[min + 1];
    System.arraycopy(oneArray, (h1 - min), t, 0, (min + 1));
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(t) + " " + (min + 1));
}
```

Maybe someone knows how to make the algorithm better?

Sometimes incorrect output. For example: 
{{-3, -3,  3, -5,  2}, {1, -2,  5, -2, -1}, {5, -3, -4,  2,  5}, {4,  4, -2,  3,  5}, {-2,  5,  4,  0,  0}}

outputs incremental:[-2, 5]
although there is [-2, 3, 5]

Comment: What is the **specific** concern?

Comment: Sometimes incorrect output. For example: {{-3, -3, 3, -5, 2}, {1, -2, 5, -2, -1}, {5, -3, -4, 2, 5}, {4, 4, -2, 3, 5}, {-2, 5, 4, 0, 0}}

outputs incremental:[-2, 5] although there is [-2, 3, 5]

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

In the code that flattens the matrix, `c` gets reset on each pass through the outer loop, so only the final row of the matrix actually makes it into `oneArray`. Moving the `int c = 0;` line out of the loop will allow the whole matrix to get copied into `oneArray` so your code can find sequences outside the final row.